# Sheaf Cohomology vs Singular Cohomology in Locally contractable Space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a space and we denote by $\mathbb{Z}_X$ the sheaf of local constant sections on $X$.

We are going to compare the sheaf cohomology $H^i(X,\mathbb{Z}_X)$ with singular cohomology $H^i(X,\mathbb{Z})$  with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ (take into account that $X$ has an underlying structure of topological space).

My question is why $H^i(X,\mathbb{Z}_X)$ and $H^i(X,\mathbb{Z})$ coinside (up to isomorphism) if every $x \in X$ has a ***contractable neighbourhood base***?

My attempts:

Denote $S_n(X):= \bigoplus_{s: \Delta_n \to X \text{ contin.}} \mathbb{Z}$ and $S^n(X):= Hom(S_n(X),\mathbb{Z})= \prod_{s: \Delta_n \to X \text{ contin.}} \mathbb{Z}$.

The differential maps are given by $$d_n: S^{n+1} \to S^n, s\mapsto \sum_{i=0} ^{n+1} (-1)^i s \vert _{\{(x_0,..., x_{n+1}) \vert x_i=0 \}}$$

this gives the complex

$$S^0(X) \to S^1(X) \to S^2(X) \to ...$$

It's $i$-th kohomology is exactly the $i-th$ singular cohomology $H^i(X,\mathbb{Z})$.

Otherwise we can define the presheaf via $V \mapsto S^n(V)$ for $V \subset X$. Denote by $\mathcal{I}^n_X$ it's sheafification.

We obtain the complex with induced differentials

$$\mathcal{I}^0 _X \to \mathcal{I}^1 _X \to \mathcal{I}^2 _X \to ...$$

One can verify that $\mathcal{I}^n_X$ are flabby and the canonical inclusion $\mathbb{Z}_X \to\mathcal{I}^0_X$ induce the complex

$$0 \to \mathbb{Z}_X  \to \mathcal{I}^0 _X \to \mathcal{I}^1 _X \to ...$$

If we would know that this complex is exact we could apply the global section functor $\Gamma(-,X)$ to this flabby resolution to obtain the desired result.

So the obstructing problem is: Why is this complex EXACT?

How does our assumption that every $x \in X$ has a ***contractable neighbourhood base*** imply it?

Comment: Did you try googling it? There's an entire arxiv article covering it from different perspectives: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.06674.pdf

Comment: @AlexYoucis: hmmm it seems that the author didn't explicitely wanted to introduce the "sheafification" instead constructed the complex $\mathcal{F}^{\bullet}$ (that seemingly coinsides with my $\mathcal{I}^{\bullet}_X$) in a circumstaneous way via a direct limit system $\mathcal{F}_{\alpha}^{\bullet} \to \mathcal{F}_{\alpha}^{\bullet}$. this is the only point that seems unclear to my why this should be done.

Comment: The rest seems ok: the exactness is a local problem $0 \to \mathbb{Z}_X  \to \mathcal{I}^0 _X \to \mathcal{I}^1 _X \to ...$ so it suffice to restrict this sequence to a contractable and affine $U$ and then the problem is equivalent to the exactness of $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to S^0(U) \to S^1(U) \to S^2(U) \to ...$. Then we can apply the cohomology to this complex und use the fact that cohomology respects homotopies so this sequence provides the same cohomology groups as $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to S^0(*) \to S^1(*) \to S^2(*) \to ...$

Comment: and this proves the exactness of the seqence since $0=H^i(*,Z)= H^i(U,Z)$ for $i \neq 0$.

Comment: Is that a rhetorical remark, or are you asking a question? If you're happy with that article feel free to just post an answer yourself. Otherwise, to try clarify what's confusing you.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: that's a half question since I'm still unsure if I understood the meaning of the neccessarity to endow $\mathcal{F}^{\bullet}$ with direct limit structure as given in the article. Since my attept (motivated by that one from article) deviates a bit from it because it not explicitely uses this limit construction and nevertheless seems to work. So the question is if that argument that I explained above is correct or did I oversee some details from Sella's paper making this limit construction/approach neccessary?